# Bootstrap Grid Offset Quetsion

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm new to Bootstrap and I came across this issue.

```
<div class="container row">
    <div id="page" class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div id="header"></div>

        <div id="article"></div>

        <div id="footer"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-1"></div>
```

In boostrap documentation it shows that I dont have to use the last div.
doc: `<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-6 .col-md-offset-3</div>
</div>`

6 + 3 = 9. There are 3 col missing. I just want to make sure I understood this well before progressing into more details.
IF there are `col` missing inside a `row` will `row` automatically add them?
Or will I have some sort of a surprise bug at the long run.

I was using the 1200px grid system before. and I always had to add the the cols in correct order and correct numbers.

Comment: Seems it won't add them. Check out this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGpydq

Comment: You need not completely write all 12 grid elements. You can use  how much ever you want (obviously less than equal to 12).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6+3= 9 & The remaining columns/grids i.e 3 columns space will remain empty, it won't give any bug, it just center align the DIV having class col-md-offset-3 by moving it 3 columns from left and 3 columns on right are empty so the DIV will be center aligned.

Hope this will bring some clarity, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First: Don't put class container and row in the same div.

Answer: If you start a new row it will start counting from zero again.

You could put all your sections in separate containers.

```
<div class='container'><!--this is your container-->
  <div class='row'><!--this is your row-->
     <div class='col-md-4 col-md-offset-3'><!--populating row with col with offset-->
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
     <!--some other cols will start counting from zero because it is a new row-->
  </div>
</div>
```